# Getting values from query SELECT in MySQL function

Tags: mysql

I have a function and i want get values from query `SELECT`.

I want to do something like: `obj = SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM table1 where id=1` and next `INSERT INTO table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) VALUES(obj->c1, obj->c2, obj->c3, 's1', 's2')`

Of course it doesn't have to be an object it can be any variable. Can u tell me how should i do this? I'm just a beginner don't blame me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you ask:

SELECT c1, c2, c3 INTO @c1, @c2, @c3 FROM table1 where id=1;

INSERT INTO table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) VALUES(@c1, @c2, @c3, 's1', 's2');

But that is not necessarily the best approach, would need more understanding of exact requirement.

Comment: You mean when `select` returns more than 1 record or u talked about  database efficiency?

Comment: this would only work for select returning one row and yes efficiency as this is creating variables etc.  The other solution:

INSERT INTO table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) SELECT c1, c2, c3, "4", "5" FROM table1 where id=1

would not create variables and accomplish the same thing, but depending on exactly how you are using it might not solve your problem.

Comment: Yes but if i want do the same into `UPDATE` already it isn't so easy as your solution, but whatever i can do LIMIT 1, and wont be any complications :)

Answer (score 2):

Simply as this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (c1, c2, c3) 
SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM table1 where id=1
```

More info [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: But if I want combine query like `INSERT into table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)` and for example c4=4 and c5=4. how should i do this then?

Comment: INSERT INTO table2 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5) 
SELECT c1, c2, c3, "4", "5" FROM table1 where id=1